# How to app.get after redirecting using express in node js

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, get

I'm a newbie in node js and here is my question.

I set the code in app.js to redirect after logging in from the login page as below,

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
  if (err) { return next(err); }
  if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
  req.flash("email");
  var email_address = req.body.email;
  var username = email_address.substring(0, email_address.lastIndexOf("@"));
  global_username = username;
  return res.redirect('/status.html'+'?channel='+username);
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

And now I want to get '/status.html'+'?channel='+username by using app.get

So I created the code like this,

```
app.get('/status.html?channel='+ global_username, isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  console.log("Logged in");
  var chk_username = req.body.email;
  var temp = chk_username.substring(0, chk_username.lastIndexOf("@"));
  if(temp != global_username){return res.json({success: false, message:"Unauthorized Attempt"});}
});
```

However, it doesn't go through that app.get function.. I tried to check whether it is logged in or not by using console.log but didn't appear anything.

Does anybody have an idea to fix this problem??

Thank you.

Comment: After redirecting the user, it ends the connection to the server, thus preventing all subsequent routing calls.  What you can do is to execute the code that you would do during the get request prior to the redirect.

Comment: @Theodore_Kim Thank you for the comment! :) then you mean I should put "app.get('/status.html?channel='+ global_username, isLoggedIn, function(req, res){ " before res.redirect('/status.html'+'?channel='+username);?

Comment: No, what I mean is that after redirecting the client, you end the response process, meaning that the server won't send anymore responses to the server for that original request.  Therefore, you won't get to the GET route after redirecting the client.  I hope that makes sense...

Comment: @Theodore_Kim oh ok I think I got it! Thank you for the answer and hope you have a great day! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so first off if you're using `global_username` as an actual global variable, that's not a great idea. It means that value changes for everyone any time anyone logs in.  I don't think that is what you want.

Also, your route should not have the querystring stuff in it at all; that's not normally part of routing, just the path stuff is.  I'm not even following what you're trying to do in that function, frankly, but the other thing you should be aware of is that there's no body in a get request, so even if you hit this middleware, you won't get a value from req.body.

If all you're trying to do is redirect to a URL and then have access to the current  user, then passport sets that in the req object for you, so you could do this:

```
app.get('/status.html, isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  console.log("Logged in");
  if (req.user) return res.send({message: 'Success'});
  return res.status(401).send({message: 'you are not logged in'});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! :D hm.. yeah you are right.. :'( I'm new to this, so I was kinda confused and trying to figure out whatever I wanted.. lol..
Anyway Thank you once again and hope you have a great day! :)

Comment: No need to apologize, I hope you're able to get it sorted based on our answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) return res.redirect('/login');
    req.flash("email");
    var email_address = req.body.email;
    var username = email_address.substring(0, email_address.lastIndexOf("@"));
    global_username = username;
    console.log("Logged in");
    var chk_username = req.body.email;
    var temp = chk_username.substring(0, chk_username.lastIndexOf("@"));
    if(temp != global_username){
      res.json({success: false, message:"Unauthorized Attempt"});
    }       

    return res.redirect('/status.html'+'?channel='+username);
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

The `res.redirect` function ends the connection between the server and client.  Therefore, it won't reach other routing requests made to it.  Basically, you want to execute your code within the function, without a secondary call.  You can still implement the GET routing for calls outside of this given instance.